# Netbeans display running without actually opening Java application window

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm new to Java and is trying to run a Java awt/javax.swing application in Netbeans. Here is the [github link](https://github.com/dzjustinli2/Tetris).

After I pressed run, nothing really happens even though Netbeans keeps displaying `running` in its window and a dot appeared under Java application icon (without actually opening a Java application window, I know this is the case because when I click the Java application icon with mouse, nothing happens).

What might be the cause of such problem?

[image]

Comment: *"Could someone please give me some suggestions on some of the **common cause** of such problem?"* The **code.**  For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: did you call `setVisible(true)`?

Comment: @FastSnail yes I did :( but thanks for the suggestion! really appreciate it!

Comment: @TonyStark how did you run it ?right click and run file?and we don't know how did you set visible.so plz add the source code.

Comment: @FastSnail I'm having trouble uploading my project to github and stackoverflow only allow less than 30000 characters :(

Comment: @TonyStark you can use pastebin.but create simple example and try to reproduce the problem then it's easy to test

Comment: Finally uploaded to github. Here is the github link: https://github.com/dzjustinli2/Tetris Thanks again for your help!

Comment: *"stackoverflow only allow less than 30000 characters"* Yes. There is a reason for that. An MCVE should be **much** shorter than 30,000 chars! And as an aside, I hope this problem gives you the hint that such trivial problems should be sorted long before the code reaches that length.

Comment: when you close your application, it will be hidden and not fully closed that's why netBeans shows running, so if you are using swing frame use `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` for your main frame, and if you are using javafx see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12154135/4101906)

Comment: Your github does not contain any Swing related code.

Comment: @rahmatwaisi Calling `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)` is the optimal approach. If there are no other threads runnning, and no other windows open, the JRE will end. OTOH if there **are** other threads running or windows opened, they should be stopped and shut down gracefully. Using `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` is like using a sledgehammer to crack a peanut shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

1: `shift + F6` to run only that file only.

2: `setVisible(true)`

Maybe it will help you...