# How to prevent code from executing after calling stage.close()?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using JavaFX.

When a certain file doesn't load, I want the stage to close and the code in that instance to stop executing.

```
catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
{
    stage.close();
    System.out.println("This should not appear.");
}
```

Calling stage.close() closes the program, but before it does, some of the other code in the program gets executed. I don't want that to happen.

How can I close the current stage immediately (or at least prevent other code from executing)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to close an entire JavaFX application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153622/how-to-close-an-entire-javafx-application)

Comment: @limonik - I don't want to close the entire application. I only want to close the current stage.

Comment: You said: "I want the stage to close and the program to stop executing.". So what do you really want to achieve? And what's that "some of other code" that get executed?

Comment: @DVarga- I may not be using the right terminology, but basically, my program starts out with one stage. That stage spawns another stage. I want the second stage to exit without affecting the first stage, and I want it to exit without continuing to call more code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `stage.setOnCloseRequest` to perform actions before your stage closes. Like

```
 public void start(Stage primaryStage)
 {
       // do all the regular stuff.
       primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(E -> {
            // perform actions before closing
       });
 }
```

Overriding the `stop()` method in your Application class is also a valid method to add a shutdown hook. Though from experiance it isn't always called when your Application shuts down.

Lastly if you want to shutdown your entire Application, please use `Platform.exit()` (static method). The `stage.close()` method is equal to `stage.hide()`, meaning only the window will be hidden, the Application will not shutdown.

EDIT1:

If you want to execute code when your stage is hiding. Use the following snippit.

```
 primaryStage.setOnHiding(E -> {
      // perform actions upon hiding.
 });
```

EDIT2:

If you want a first Stage to wait for a second Stage, and continu after the second Stage is closed use `secondaryStage.showAndWait()`. This way you just close the secondary Stage if you want to continu with the execution on the first Stage.

Comment: I've tried Platform.exit, but it closes more than just the current stage. It also closes the other stages as well. It also doesn't prevent the code after it.

Comment: The way that I'm creating the second stage is with `Application game = `gameType.newInstance(); Stage newStage = new Stage(); game.start(newStage);` I don't think that showAndWait would work there, since the game object is creating its own stage.

Comment: You create 2 apllication class instances? Thats a bad idea. Use only one, and for the second stage do `newStage.showAndWait()`. It will give the results you need.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but if you always want the stage to close when `FileNotFoundException` is thrown, why would you put some code inside the `catch` block that you never want to execute? Put all the code you don't want execute if the stage is closed inside the `try` block, and then the `stage.close()` statement in the `catch` block. This way the code in the `try` block will only get executed if no exception is thrown.