# How to close entire app when a TornadoFX window is closed?

Tags: java, kotlin, tornadofx

How can I close the entire app when a TornadoFX window is closed?

With JavaFX it is usually:

```
val app = JFrame()
app.defaultCloseOperation = JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE
```

Is there a way to detect on TornadoFX View closed?

Comment: [How to close a JavaFX application on window close?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153622/how-to-close-a-javafx-application-on-window-close)

Comment: @Abra This is for a TornadoFX app.

Comment: "With JavaFX it is usually:

`val app = JFrame()
app.defaultCloseOperation = JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`" Except that's _Swing_, not _JavaFX_. Also, note that TornadoFX is, at its core, simply a Kotlin framework on top of JavaFX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, closing the primary stage activates the App class's `stop()` function. This is what you want to override to do your own shutdown routine:

```
class MyApp : App (FirstView::class) {
    override fun stop() {
        super.stop()
        /* Do your shutdown routine here  */
    }
}
```

However, I've had instances where that logic gets broken and only closing all program windows works. If you have a 'main window' that you want to ensure shuts down the program, add this in your App class as well:

```
override fun start(stage: Stage) {
   stage.setOnHiding { stop() }
}
```

Edit: I would use your IDE to look at what exactly the `stop()` function does for you, as well as look at the answers linked by Abra to see what the vanilla JavaFX `Platform.exit()` function does as TornadoFX is just JavaFX at its core, and this is most explicit shutdown of a JavaFX application. Some users in that thread reported that their program would still hang depending on what they were doing and suggested adding `System.exit(0);`, aka `exitProcess(0)` in Kotlin, to their shutdown routine to make sure the program dies.

Comment: "Usually, closing the primary stage activates the App class's stop() function. [...] However, I've had instances where that logic gets broken and only closing all program windows works". That's not broken logic. As documented [here](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html) and [here](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Platform.html#setImplicitExit(boolean)), if configured to implicitly exit, the shutdown procedure only starts when the **last** window is closed, not necessarily when the primary stage is closed.

Comment: And if you want to explicitly stop the JavaFX runtime then you need to call [`Platform#exit()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Platform.html#exit()). The `Application#stop()` method is just a life-cycle method that's invoked at the appropriate time; it doesn't activate that part of the life-cycle and should probably never be invoked manually.

Comment: @Slaw that doesn't seem right. I've made programs that call the TornadoFX `App.stop()` function only when the primary stage window is closed, even if there are other windows open that don't have owners.

Comment: Then there was something wrong, possibly a bug in JavaFX itself, because that's not what's documented to happen. Personally, I've never encountered that problem.

Comment: @Slaw I think you are confusing JavaFX's `Application#stop()` with TornadoFX's `App#stop()`.

Comment: Possibly. Though the KDocs show [`App`](https://tornadofx.io/dokka/tornadofx/tornadofx/-app/index.html) extends from `Application` and make no mention of changing how and when `stop()` is invoked. Not finding anything in the [Wiki](https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx/wiki) or [TornadoFX Guide](https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/content/) about a difference in behavior either, though I could have missed it.

Comment: Yes, but there are two things to keep in mind: 1. JavaFX's `Application#stop()` method is an empty method. TornadoFX definitely adds its own functionality. 2. Stage handling is different due to TornadoFX's implementation. I haven't explored deeply into TornadoFX's lifecycle management but I wouldn't be surprised that it adds onto JavaFX handling of just when `stop()` is called. I also wouldn't be surprised if it's not full-proof, as TornadoFX requires proper calls to track stage life-cycles which are buggy anyways.

Comment: TornadoFX builds a framework, in Kotlin, on top of JavaFX. Part of this involves setting up container-like code which needs to be properly disposed of and which it appears to do in its implementation of the `stop()` method. If TornadoFX is changing how the life-cycle of JavaFX is handled I would consider that a bug. The `stop()` method should only be invoked when the entire application is exiting. As the `App` class seems to be TornadoFX's equivalent of `Application` in a plain JavaFX application, it doesn't make sense to invoke `stop()` when part of the application is still running.